# Is the command \underscore used in any packages?

Tags: typewriter

I've noticed that the underscore produced with `\textunderscore` doesn't get matched when I search the resulting PDF for it. Does any one know of an `\underscore` (or perhaps `\uscore`) command to produce a searchable underscore already defined in a package?

I came across `\texttt{\symbol{95}}` and `` \texttt{\char`_} ``. Are they  equivalent?

Comment: (1) Almost certainly. It is an obvious thing to define, so very likely *some* package defines it. (2) Won't it depend on the encoding? Although it may be one of the slots which TeX needs to have a given character in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only find `\underscore` defined in the `syntax` package. The package is rather old and has been unmaintained for 20 years. Its definition of `\underscore` mimicks that of `\_` when a font encoding without the underscore is used; the package documentation says

> The package also includes some other features […]
>   • A slightly different underscore character, which works as expected in text
>   and maths modes.

I find no occurrence of `\uscore`.

Finally, `\texttt{\symbol{95}}` is almost equivalent to `` \texttt{\char`_} ``, with the difference that the former is better. If you don't want to look up tables, you can use

```
\texttt{\symbol{`\_}}
```

which gets the best of both worlds. Using `\char<number>` can be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `\underscore`:

If you need `\underscore` to be defined, but are concerned that some unknown package might define it, you can do this after `\begin{document}`:

```
\providecommand\underscore{\_}
```

Then `\underscore` will print the underscore character. However, if some package already defined `\underscore`, then it will do whatever that package defined it to do (which may or may not print the underscore character).